# nodejs in cluster mode

Tags: node.js

```
const express = require("express");

const app = express();

const doWork = () => {
  const start = Date.now();
  while (Date.now() - start < 5000) {}
};

app.get("/slow", (req, res) => {
  doWork();
  res.send("slow");
});

app.get("/fast", (req, res) => {
  res.send("fast");
});

app.listen(3000);
```

1. if i first go to /slow in one tab after that just immediately /fast in another, both take about 5 seconds
2. if i first go to /slow in one tab after that just immediately /slow in another 1st takes about 5 seconds, 2nd about 10

this is as node is single threaded

now i try the same behavior with the following -

```
const express = require("express");
const cluster = require("cluster");

if (cluster.isMaster) {
  cluster.fork();
  cluster.fork();
  cluster.fork();
  cluster.fork();
} else {
  const app = express();

  const doWork = () => {
    const start = Date.now();
    while (Date.now() - start < 5000) {}
  };

  app.get("/slow", (req, res) => {
    doWork();
    res.send("slow");
  });

  app.get("/fast", (req, res) => {
    res.send("fast");
  });

  app.listen(3000);
}
```

1. if i first go to /slow in one tab after that just immediately /fast in another, 1st takes 5 seconds, 2nd happens immediately
2. if i first go to /slow in one tab after that just immediately /slow in another 1st takes about 5 seconds, 2nd about 10 **(why is this happening)**

the above also happens when i try to use [pm2](https://pm2.keymetrics.io/) i mean running the first code of the question using pm2

Comment: I just tested your cluster example and fast always loaded instantly. only when I had 5 slows running did I sometimes have to wait for fast 

Comment: How many cores does your computer have?

Comment: thanks for responding!
my cpu has 4 logical cores (from what i understand)
here is a screenshot of lscpu
https://ibb.co/7khtDDy
also  ur first comment is right, as i said, i am facing issue only with 2 /slow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added some more logging:

```
app.get("/slow", (req, res) => {
    console.log(`${process.pid} GET /slow start`)
    doWork();
    res.send("slow");
    console.log(`${process.pid} GET /slow end`)
  });
```

and it looks like the same worker is getting all the `/slow` requests
[image: terminal showing all requests to /slow have the same process ID]
But didn't block `/fast` for me

So I tried in firefox, and there the first 4 `/slow` requests were all sent to different workers.

Looking at the connection headers, node is sending the `Connection: keep-alive` header, so I think that Chrome is trying to re-use the one connection between tabs, which is leading to requests being queued.

You can confirm this by inspecting the `Connection ID` in chrome's devtools (with "Disable cache" turned off). All the IDs are the same between `/slow` tabs

This means you might be able to get more concurrency by disabling keep-alive. But since connections will only be re-used by the same user, it might not be a huge issue